# Comparing Dates in Case Statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I couldn't able to compare the date in case statement

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got DATE
>   00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Here , I want to replace the `enter code here` START_DATE_ACTIVE with PROJECT_START_DATE when it lesser than PROJECT_START_DATE.

[image: Please refer the data here]

```
(
CASE WHEN TO_DATE(PPP.START_DATE_ACTIVE,'DD/MM/YY') < 
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(PPA.PROJECT_START_DATE,'yyyy/mm/dd'),'DD-MM- 
  YY'),'DD/MM/YY')
   THEN PPA.PROJECT_START_DATE
   ELSE PPP.START_DATE_ACTIVE
END
)                                          START_DATE_ACTIVE
```

Expected Result

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: Are your dates stored using a date type or are they varchars?

Comment: Your sample data shows dates in two different formats. That couldn't happen if both columns have a DATE datatype. Please post full table details and real sample data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer:

```
(CASE WHEN TO_DATE (PPP.START_DATE_ACTIVE,'DD/MM/YY') < 
 TO_DATE (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(PPA.PROJECT_START_DATE,'yyyy/mm/dd'),'DD-MM-YY'),'DD/MM/YY')
 THEN TO_DATE (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(PPA.PROJECT_START_DATE,'yyyy/mm/dd'),'DD-MM-YY'),'DD/MM/YY')
 ELSE TO_DATE (PPP.START_DATE_ACTIVE,'DD/MM/YY')
 END
```

)

The result field date format should be same as your comparing date format.

Comment: None of this is necessary since the fields are dates to start with.  All you've done is converted a date to a character back to a date... quite unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

If your dates are actually stored in date fields you don't have to convert them to characters you can test them as dates.

```
(
 CASE WHEN PPP.START_DATE_ACTIVE < PPA.PROJECT_START_DATE
   THEN PPA.PROJECT_START_DATE
   ELSE PPP.START_DATE_ACTIVE
END
)   START_DATE_ACTIVE
```

Comment: The dates are stored in data fields as date type. I tried to convert both date into date in same format and compared but it failed

Comment: Since they are dates you don't have to do any conversion in order to do comparison.

Comment: @K_PREMNATH do you also convert numbers to numbers using `to_number()`? Do you convert characters to characters using `to_char`? There is no need. A `date` is already a `date`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have indicated once a date is properly contained within a DATE type there is no need to use to_date or to_char to perform data manipulation. Those routines are necessary only to convert from/to a human readable form. But that may not be the full story.
The Oracle DATE type contain both date and time components. It seems the multiple conversions are often an attempt to remove the time component. But even that is not necessary. The trunc function is available for that (actually it sets the time to 00:00:00). If it's the case here that you want just the date component then your case statement reduces to

```
case
    when trunc(ppp.start_date_active) < trunc(ppa.project_start_date)
    then trunc(ppa.project_start_date)
    else trunc(ppp.start_date_active)
end start_date_active;
```

But that can be reduced to a single line as:

```
trunc(greatest(start_date_active,project_start_date)) start_date_active
```